# socket.io-stream createStream is not a function in browser

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, node-modules, es6-modules

I have been having quite a lot of issues trying to make `socket.io-stream` work lately. I am writing a Vue3 application that may need to send large files to an Express server.

Looking at the Github page for the module I saw that to get it to work on the browser I needed to copy the `node_modules/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js` file into a public directory. So I copied it to `src`. I also added a declaration file with `declare module '@/socket.io-stream'` inside to make sure the import works.

This is the code I have on the client side

```
import * as ss from '@/socket.io-stream';

const stream = ss.createStream();
```

However despite the import working (no squiggly and I have intellisense of the `ss` object), I'm getting a `ss.createStream is not a function` error.

When console logging the `ss` object I'm also only getting

```
0bject { … }
    Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

Does anyone know how to make `socket.io-stream` work on the browser and with ES modules? I also tried the browserify method but it didn't change anything and importing from the file inside `node_modules` resulted in a `Process is not defined`